# Exchange 2010: how to delete specific folder and subfolders in user mailbox

Tags: exchange, mailbox

Just simple question: any tool|script that simply allow admin delete **specifed folder** and his subfolders in **user** Mailbox?
Without export/import.

Read some answers on technet, in microsoft blogs - Exchange has nice front and ugly back.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Administrator privileges, you can enable **[Full Access Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676551%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)** on the mailbox to the Administrator or your personal account.

From there, the user's mailbox will be fully accessible in your account (or the Administrator's account). You can make changes to the folder structure there.